# Five letters are to be selected from the letters of the word 'ADVANTAGE'. How many different combinations (not permutations) are there?

Tags: combinatorics

Have I got the correct answer and is there an easier way of achieving the correct solution?

[image: attempted_solution]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to math Stack Exchange. Please, include your solution in your question, not just the image of a hand-written solution.

Comment: To add to @Ramiro 's comment.  You could summarize the solution instead of putting all the details.

Comment: MathJax tutorial for math typesetting http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: At least orientate your image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word ADVANTAGE has $7$ distinct letters: $3$ A's, $1$ D's , $1$ V's , $1$ N's , $1$ T's , $1$ G's and $1$ E's .

So in how many ways can you exactly choose $5$ letters here? 
Let us list them.

1. $5$ distinct letters
2. $3$ identical letters and $2$ distinct letters
3. $2$ identical letters and $3$ distinct letters

Hence, there are $3$ such ways.

Now for the calculation part: in $(1)$, we have ${7\choose 5}=21$ choices ; in $(2)$, we have ${1\choose 1}\cdot{6\choose 2}=15$ choices and in $(3)$, we have ${1\choose 1}\cdot{6\choose 3}=20$ choices.

> ***Note***: The ${1\choose 1}$ comes from the fact there is only one triplet i.e. $3$ A's and only one duplet i.e. $2$ A's.

Total no. of choices = $\color{blue}{56}$.

Comment: This is, essentially, what is linked to in the original question.  But, it's good to have a complete answer.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Oh, actually I never looked into that link. However, after you just told me, I checked it and found that although the working is similar to mine, the logic is quite incomplete.

Comment: I agree with your comment about the logic (+1)

Answer (score 1):

This is not easier, but it is a little fun.  The generating function for this question is $(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x)^6$.  The first term represents the $A$'s while the second term represents the distinct letters.  The coefficient of $x^5$ is the number of combinations that are possible.  (Generating functions are a little hard to get started with, but they're very useful once you understand them).

Method 1: Using the binomial theorem, we know that
$$
(1+x)^6=\sum_{i=0}^6\binom{6}{i}x^i.
$$
Therefore, the number of solutions is 
$$
\binom{6}{5}+\binom{6}{4}+\binom{6}{3}+\binom{6}{2}=56.
$$

Method 2: Using derivatives.  To get the coefficient of $x^5$, we take the 5th derivative:
$$
\frac{d^5}{dx^5}((1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x)^6)=\binom{5}{0}(1+x+x^2+x^3)\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(1+x)^6+\binom{5}{1}\frac{d}{dx}(1+x+x^2+x^3)\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(1+x)^6+\binom{5}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x+x^2+x^3)\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(1+x)^6+\binom{5}{3}\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(1+x+x^2+x^3)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x)^6.
$$
We don't need any more derivatives because any higher derivative will make $(1+x+x^2+x^3)$ zero.  These derivatives are fairly easy to calculate:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^6&=6(1+x)^5&\frac{d}{dx}(1+x+x^2+x^3)&=(1+2x+3x^2)\\
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x)^6&=30(1+x)^4&\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x+x^2+x^3)&=(2+6x)\\
\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(1+x)^6&=120(1+x)^3&\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(1+x+x^2+x^3)&=6\\
\frac{d^4}{dx^4}(1+x)^6&=360(1+x)^2\\
\frac{d^5}{dx^5}(1+x)^6&=720(1+x).
\end{align*}
Therefore, the long expression from above becomes
$$
(1+x+x^2+x^3)(720(1+x))+5(1+2x+3x^2)(360(1+x)^2)+10(2+6x)(120(1+x)^3)+10(6)30(1+x)^4.
$$
Since we've taken the fifth derivative, the coefficient of the $x^5$th is now part of the constant term, so we can set $x=0$ to eliminate everything else.  This gives that the expression simplifies to
$$
720+1800+2400+1800=7620.
$$
Finally, since were were interested in the coefficient of $x^5$, we had $cx^5$.  After $5$ derivatives, the constant term is $5!c$.  Dividing $7620$ by $5!$ gives us $56$, the desired answer.

Comment: Making simple solution complicated but useful in bigger things like $13$ letter

Answer (score 1):

In the word `ADVANTAGE` there are $3$ `A` and $6$ other letters (all distinct).

So in order to calculate the number of $5$-letter combinations, add up the following:

- Number of combinations with $\color\red0$ `A` is $\binom{6}{5-\color\red0}= 6$
- Number of combinations with $\color\red1$ `A` is $\binom{6}{5-\color\red1}=15$
- Number of combinations with $\color\red2$ `A` is $\binom{6}{5-\color\red2}=20$
- Number of combinations with $\color\red3$ `A` is $\binom{6}{5-\color\red3}=15$